# word count using awk for the sample file

Tags: unix, awk

**`The awk script should produce a table that lists words with more than 4 letters and more than 2 occurrences. The last line of the output should display the number of words in the file.`**

Input file

```
In navigation, the heading of a vessel or aircraft is the compass direction
in which the craft's bow or nose is pointed. Note that the heading may not
#necessarily be the direction that the vehicle actually travels, which is
known as its course or track. Any difference between the heading and
course is due to the motion of the underlying medium, the air or water,
or other effects like skidding or slipping. The difference is known as
the drift, and can be determined by the wind triangle. At least seven ways
to measure the heading of a vehicle have been described. A compass installed
in a vehicle or vessel has a certain amount of error caused by the magnetic 
properties of the vessel. This error is known as compass deviation. The 
magnitude of the compass deviation varies greatly depending upon the local 
anomalies created by the vessel. A fiberglass recreational vessel will 
#generally have much less compass deviation than a steel-hulled vessel. 
Electrical wires carrying current have a small magnetic field around them 
and can cause deviation. Any type of magnet, such as found in a speaker 
can also cause large magnitudes of compass deviation. The error can be 
corrected using a deviation table. Deviation tables are very difficult to 
create. Once a deviation table is established, it is only good for that 
particular vessel, with that particular configuration. If electrical wires 
are moved or anything else magnetic (speakers, electric motors, etc.) are 
moved, the deviation table will change. All deviations in the deviation 
table are indicated west or east. If the compass is pointing west of the 
Magnetic North Pole, then the deviation is westward. If the compass is 
pointing east of the Magnetic North Pole, then the deviation is eastward.
```

1. Write an awk script that produces a report from an input file.
   The report counts the number of times a word occurs in the input file.**
2. Separately implement the additional functionality that ignores punctuation characters such as `".,;:()".*`

`cat input.txt|awk -F" "'{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}'`

outcome I expect [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q9Xp.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so].  What have you tried so far, which problem(s) did you run into?

Comment: And what was the outcome, what outcome did you expect? Again - edit the question, don't add comments.

Comment: Don't include links or images in your question, just text. It doesn't take that large paragraph of text for you to provide an example that demonstrates your problem for us to use to test with - please create and post a [mcve]. Should the counts be case-sensitive or not?

Comment: When you have `craft's` do you consider this to be single word with length of 7 or two separate words `craft` and `s`?

Comment: its a single word

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** this looks (to me) like a homework assignment so I'm just going to address current code.

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++ }             # remains the same
END  { for (k in a) { 
           total+=a[k]                           # keep track of total word count
           if ( a[k] > 2 && length(k) > 4 )      # apply filters to limit output
              print k,a[k]
       }
       printf "\nTotal: %s\n", total
     }
' input.txt
```

This generates:

```
compass 8
deviation 8       # +1 for 'Deviation'                 ?
deviation. 3      # need to strip "."
error 3
heading 4
known 3
magnetic 3        # +2 for 'Magnetic'                  ?
table 3           # +1 for 'table.'                    ?
vehicle 3
vessel 3          # +1 for 'vessel,'                   ?
vessel. 3         # need to strip "."
                  # +2 for 'moved' & 'moved.'          ?
                  # +2 for 'electrical' & 'Electrical' ?
Total: 292
```

**NOTES:**

- no sorting requirements have been provided (I piped through `sort -f` to generate this output so it's easier to see where potential issues need to be addressed)
- assuming OP's desired output (in the image) is a subset of what's expected (eg, `vehicle` does not show up in OP's output; my script found `compass 8` while OP's (image) shows `compass 7`)
- assuming `number of words in file` applies to **ALL** words and not just those of `length > 4` and `count > 2` (I found `292` while OP's output shows `271`); otherwise OP will need to add logic to determine if `a[$i]++` should be performed
- OP needs to implement additional logic to strip out punctuation **before** performing the `a[$i]++` (hint: `gsub()` or `gensub()` functions)
- does OP need to implement case-insensitive storage of words for counting purposes? if so this will increase the number of hits for some words (eg, `magnetic` and `deviation`) (hint: `tolower()` function)

Comment: It's a worksheet problem, not a homework assignment.